# Wrong zoom in/out behavior touchpad move

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, scrolling, zooming

Scenario:

1. Being in browser, I drag the touchpad using two fingers -> page scroll
2. While the page is scrolling (my fingers are not on touchpad anymore), I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.
3. The page is zoomed in/out

Same issue appears in Nautilus, for example.

How can this be fixed?